# SQL-Query pull different values from 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build an sql query where I need to call on all the parts that are active, inactive, and new. The parts are under the parts table and here is the tricky part so the state of the parts are all under one table as well. so it looks like this:

```
        ID  State
        0   Historic
        1   Active
        2   Inactive
        3   New
        4   Historic - Invalid
```

how can I pull out 3 values from the same column for the parts?

Comment: provide a code of Parts table

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question.  Are you just looking to get the data where the State column reads 'Active', 'Inactive', or 'new'?  Do you want the ID, the State, or both?

```
SELECT ID, State from parts WHERE State = 'Active' OR State = 'Inactive' OR State = 'new';
```

should give both columns where the State is either `Active`, `Inactive`, or `new`.  Does that address your problem?  Or did you mean you've got a state table (what you showed) and a separate parts table and you need to combine them?  That might look like:

```
SELECT * FROM parts LEFT JOIN state ON parts.state_id = state.id WHERE state.State = 'Active' OR state.State = 'Inactive' OR state.State = 'new';
```

...depending on the formatting and naming used in your tables.

Comment: Im sorry I fixed the state table now. So I am trying to get all the parts from the part table where they are classified as active, inactive, and new so I want the SELECT statement to contain the state along with the partnumber and I am adding in the WHERE clause that the id= 1,2 etc.,So I did use the the OR statement like you did but but the query is taking too long to execute and I am still waiting for it, thats why I want to try something different but I am not sure what

Comment: Can you tell me all the column names for both tables?  Also how many entries are in each table?  If your query is running too slowly it's probably because you need an index somewhere where there's not one at the moment.  Give me all the column names and the exact query you ran, and I probably suggest where you might add an index.

Answer (score 0):

Hey everyone thank you for the help I finally figured it out so like @DericMiller stated use the OR but I wasnt adding paranthesis so the order of operations was messed up but after adding the OR statements with the parenthesis it worked! The code is like this:

```
                                                                             JOIN p_statehistory ph ON ph.CID=ch.CID AND (ph.CID=1 OR ph.CID=2 OR ph.CID=3)
```